# How to connect / auth users to Oracle pluggable DB using SQL developer

Tags: oracle, oracle-sql-developer

I am struggling connecting to a pluggable DB for which I created local users.

I have an Oracle 21c XE on my machine.
The CDB is XE.
I logged into SID=XE with sys as sysdba.
There I created a PDB as follows:

```
create pluggable database GRE
    admin user manager identified by manager
    roles = (dba)
    file_name_convert = ('C:\ORADATA\XE\PDBSEED', 'C:\ORADATA\XE\GRE')
;

ALTER PLUGGABLE DATABASE GRE OPEN;
```

Then I switched to the pluggable DB:

```
alter session set container = GRE;
select sys_context('USERENV', 'CON_NAME') from dual;

SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','CON_NAME')
GRE
```

Then I created a user and assigned roles and priviledges:

```
-- USER SQL
CREATE USER "user1" IDENTIFIED BY "user1"  
DEFAULT TABLESPACE "DATA"
TEMPORARY TABLESPACE "TEMP" container=current;

-- QUOTAS
ALTER USER "user1" QUOTA UNLIMITED ON "DATA";

-- ROLES
GRANT "CONNECT" TO "user1" ;
GRANT "RESOURCE" TO "user1" ;
ALTER USER "user1" DEFAULT ROLE "CONNECT","RESOURCE";

-- SYSTEM PRIVILEGES
GRANT DROP ANY MATERIALIZED VIEW TO "user1" ;
GRANT CREATE ANY SYNONYM TO "user1" ;
GRANT DROP ANY SYNONYM TO "user1" ;
GRANT DROP ANY VIEW TO "user1" ;
GRANT CREATE ANY VIEW TO "user1" ;
GRANT CREATE ANY MATERIALIZED VIEW TO "user1" ;
```

This is the output of `lsnrctl status`:

```
Services Übersicht...
Dienst "541e76d5c7264140b887e5606a1a0486" hat 1 Instanzen.
  Instanz "xe", Status READY, hat 2 Handler für diesen Dienst...
Dienst "CLRExtProc" hat 1 Instanzen.
  Instanz "CLRExtProc", Status UNKNOWN, hat 1 Handler für diesen Dienst...
Dienst "XE" hat 1 Instanzen.
  Instanz "xe", Status READY, hat 2 Handler für diesen Dienst...
Dienst "XEXDB" hat 1 Instanzen.
  Instanz "xe", Status READY, hat 1 Handler für diesen Dienst...
Dienst "gre" hat 1 Instanzen.
  Instanz "xe", Status READY, hat 2 Handler für diesen Dienst...
Der Befehl wurde erfolgreich ausgeführt.
```

It can be seen that the PDB `gre` is available.

When I try to connect to the PDB using the local user, the login is denied with ORA-01017.

[image: Login details in SQL Developer]

I tried to figure out how to deal with PDBs and local users, but I am unable to understand how I can get this working. Maybe I understand the concept wrongly, and I need to use common users and connect to the CDB first and from there switch to the PDB?

Comment: You need to connect to the PDB using its service_name, not the SID. SID will always connect you to the CDB. Use `lsnrctl status` to get a list of active service names for the server.

Comment: I made the connection to SID only to create the PDB, when connecting to the PDB, I used its service name, which I read from `lsnrctl status`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not related to the Multitenant architecture.

Unfortunately you created the user with a case-sensitive username by using double quotes.

The username in SQL Developer should be `"user1"` instead of `user1`.

Comment: oh, thank you for this hint. When I looked in SQL Developer DBA view under Security / Users, the " were not visible and the user names looked ok.